# What would be the worldwide response if Russia launches a nuke into Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nuclear-weapons

As NATO would not be directly involved, Article 5 would not be invoked. However, I presume a nuclear launch at Ukraine by Russia wouldn't go without a response. What (if any) international agreements (NATO, UN, etc) would guide a response by the international community to such an event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Russia not using nuclear weapons against Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71106/why-is-russia-not-using-nuclear-weapons-against-ukraine)

Comment: I think we can safely say "negative." No one has done that since WWII, and even with Nazi Germany, Fascist Italy, and Imperial Japan having an...unpopular...reputation in most of the world at the time, it was not precisely well received. But beyond that, it is speculation.

Comment: Still, why would they? Nearly every currently nuclear-armed country has been involved in wars since 1945, some against each other, and none has used them.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is closed as opinion based, and I'm not receiving any help from anyone on how to correct this. I'm not seeing any difference in the question from e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71175/are-there-any-checks-and-balances-against-nuclear-escalation-in-russia . Any help please?

Comment: if your question is the same as the other, it's not needed.

Comment: I meant there's no difference in terms of being opinion based.